# How can you make a stacked area / line chart in Julia with Plots.jl?

Tags: plot, julia, stacked-area-chart

I would like to create a stacked area chart, similar [to this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html) for example, in Julia using Plots.

I know / suppose that you can do this if you directly use the Gadfly or PyPlot backends in Julia, but I was wondering if there was a recipe for this. If not, how can you contribute to the Plots Recipes? Would be a useful addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a recipe for something similar in

https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/examples/pgfplots/#portfolio-composition-maps

For some reason the thumbnail looks broken now though (but the code works).

The exact plot in the matlab example can be produced by

```
plot(cumsum(Y, dims = 2)[:,end:-1:1], fill = 0, lc = :black)
```

As a recipe that would look like

```
@userplot AreaChart
@recipe function f(a::AreaChart)
         fillto --> 0
         linecolor --> :black
         seriestype --> :path
         cumsum(a.args[1], dims = 2)[:,end:-1:1]
       end
```

If you want to contribute a recipe to Plots you can open a pull request on Plots, or, eg. on StatsPlots - there's a good description of contributing here: https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/contributing/

It's a bit of reading, but very generally useful as an introduction to contributing to Julia packages.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-plot-a-simple-stacked-area-chart/21351) in the Julia discourse forum where the question is developed in deep.

One solution posted there using Plots is :

```
# a simple "recipe" for Plots.jl to get stacked area plots
# usage: stackedarea(xvector, datamatrix, plotsoptions)
@recipe function f(pc::StackedArea)
    x, y = pc.args
    n = length(x)
    y = cumsum(y, dims=2)
    seriestype := :shape

    # create a filled polygon for each item
    for c=1:size(y,2)
        sx = vcat(x, reverse(x))
        sy = vcat(y[:,c], c==1 ? zeros(n) : reverse(y[:,c-1]))
        @series (sx, sy)
    end
end

a = [1,1,1,1.5,2,3]
b = [0.5,0.6,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.2]
c = [2,1.8,2.2,3.3,2.5,1.8]
sNames = ["a","b","c"]
x = [2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006]

plotly()
stackedarea(x, [a b c], labels=reshape(sNames, (1,3)))
```

(by user NiclasMattsson)

Other ways presented there include using the [VegaLite.jl](https://github.com/fredo-dedup/VegaLite.jl) package.

Comment: A little curious why you'd answer two hours later with a significantly more verbose and unclear solution? That solution also prevents the user from setting the properties of the lines separating the slices.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard  Well, that's subjective. I appreciate your answer, but I (subjectively) think the solution I posted (for which I take no credit) is more clear. Also posting to the link to the thread in discourse I show that there are other solutions that has been already posted to do that or similar things, like getting the area normalised.